# Codenameone compilation error trying to compile for IOS (debug) with camera error

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, compilation, camera, codenameone

App uses using camera Capture class and not CameraKit library
Android compiles and builds without any issues.

Codenameone app was compiling to ios (debug) without any issues now seeing :

> CompileC
>   build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApplication/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApplication.build/Release-iphoneos/MyApplication.build/Objects-normal/arm64/com_codename1_camerakit_impl_CameraNativeAccessImpl.o
>   MyApplication-src/com_codename1_camerakit_impl_CameraNativeAccessImpl.m
>   normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>       cd /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist
>       export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode9.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode9.2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode9.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -x objective-c -arch arm64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c99 -gmodules -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O3 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wno-non-literal-null-conversion -Wno-objc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DCOCOAPODS=1 -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode9.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk
>   -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-infinite-recursion -Wno-comma -Wno-block-capture-autoreleasing -Wno-strict-prototypes -iquote /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApplication/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApplication.build/Release-iphoneos/MyApplication.build/MyApplication-generated-files.hmap
>   -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApplication/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApplication.build/Release-iphoneos/MyApplication.build/MyApplication-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApplication/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApplication.build/Release-iphoneos/MyApplication.build/MyApplication-all-target-headers.hmap
>   -iquote /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApplication/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApplication.build/Release-iphoneos/MyApplication.build/MyApplication-project-headers.hmap
>   -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApplication/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/include
>   -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public
>   -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps
>   -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApplication/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApplication.build/Release-iphoneos/MyApplication.build/DerivedSources/arm64
>   -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApplication/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApplication.build/Release-iphoneos/MyApplication.build/DerivedSources
>   -F/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApplication/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
>   -F/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/Pods/GoogleMaps/Base/Frameworks
>   -F/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks
>   -isystem /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public
>   -isystem /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps
>   -include /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApplication/PrecompiledHeaders/MyApplication-Prefix-hbgltpkgcmoawieqkjnaxxjtmvsn/MyApplication-Prefix.pch
>   -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApplication/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApplication.build/Release-iphoneos/MyApplication.build/Objects-normal/arm64/com_codename1_camerakit_impl_CameraNativeAccessImpl.d
>   --serialize-diagnostics /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApplication/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApplication.build/Release-iphoneos/MyApplication.build/Objects-normal/arm64/com_codename1_camerakit_impl_CameraNativeAccessImpl.dia
>   -c /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/MyApplication-src/com_codename1_camerakit_impl_CameraNativeAccessImpl.m
>   -o /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApplication/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApplication.build/Release-iphoneos/MyApplication.build/Objects-normal/arm64/com_codename1_camerakit_impl_CameraNativeAccessImpl.o
>   /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7095351684558952468xxx/dist/MyApplication-src/com_codename1_camerakit_impl_CameraNativeAccessImpl.m:2:10:
>   fatal error: 'com_codename1_camerakit_impl_CameraCallbacks.h' file not
>   found
>
> ## include "com_codename1_camerakit_impl_CameraCallbacks.h"
>
> ```
>     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> 1 error generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because you installed the cn1lib in the past and didn't remove it. On Android this will include the cn1lib anyway and you'll just have a bit of overhead but on iOS we strip unused code. (Notice that on Android the obfuscation stage will probably remove the library code).

Unfortunately the native code in the library can't detect that this stripping of unused code occurred and would result in this compilation error.

See this: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-uninstall-cn1lib.html